# Removing a canvas from page and replacing it with a simple text message

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to remove a canvas from the page and replace it with a message. This is what I have:

```
<div id="1">
<div class="2">
<canvas>
</div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is to remove the canvas and replace it with a message, a simple message that says something like: "things have been disconnected".

I am trying:

$("#1 .2").innerHtml = "What I want to say"

but that did not remove the canvas, I am just wondering why and if there is a better way to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remember to close your `canvas` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("1")
        .getElementsByTagName("div")[0]
        .innerHTML = "What I want to say";
```

JQuery:

```
$("#1 .2").html("What I want to say");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery, no?

```
$("#1 .2").html("What I want to say");
```